# Is possible to capture KeyDown event when current document is in design mode?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, xhtml, rich-text-editor

As you know, most of rich text editor use iframe to create WYSIWYG editor. In iframe contain document that is in design mode. I want to capture key down event when user press '@' character in rich text editor for displaying autocomplete for it.

By the way, i cannot see any fired event inside design mode. How can I solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to capture all key events in documents with `designMode` turned on, though you have to use `addEventListener` on `document` in Firefox (and possibly others) rather than assigning your handler to `document.onkeypress`.

To capture the user typing the '@' character (or indeed any printable character), you should use the `keypress` event rather than `keydown`.

```
// Assuming you have a reference to your iframe in a variable called 'iframe':

function handleIframeKeyPress(evt) {
    evt = evt || iframe.contentWindow.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (charTyped === "@") {
        alert("@ typed");
    }
}

var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

if (doc.addEventListener) {
    doc.addEventListener("keypress", handleIframeKeyPress, false);
} else if (doc.attachEvent) {
    doc.attachEvent("onkeypress", handleIframeKeyPress);
} else {
    doc.onkeypress = handleIframeKeyPress;
}
```